# Is mapping cylinder of a discontinuous function a thing?

Tags: general-topology

I am reading Hatcher's Algebraic Topology and its definition of mapping cylinder does not say the deriving function needs to be continuous. But such a requirement is mentioned in [nlab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/mapping+cylinder) and  [encyclopedia of mathematics](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Mapping_cylinder). In Hatcher's, later it says the "targeting subspace" $Y$ is a deformation retract of the mapping cylinder derived from mapping $X \to Y$. But this seems to be only true if the mapping is continuous. Is this correct?

I further checked some other sources and it seems several of them don't require the mapping to be continuous. So I assume in such a case, $Y$ is not a deformation retract of the mapping cylinder. But then, is such a motion of a mapping cylinder from a discontinuous function really a thing?

Comment: “Mappings” are always continuous

Comment: I suppose in topology it is basically always assumed that all your functions are continuous

Comment: Hatcher (page 1, just below the title of the chapter) says: *To avoid overusing the word "continuous" we adopt the convention that maps between spaces are always assumed to be continuous unless otherwise stated*

Comment: Thanks all! This all makes sense now!